# GeneratePackageOnBuild NU5118 resources.dll

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget-package, csproj

in my solutions there are two libraries:

- The library I want to ship as a nuget package (let's call it EntryLibrary)
- The library, where I store the translations using RESX files (Translations)

The translations library `csproj` looks like (nothing fancy):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="Strings.Designer.cs">
            <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
            <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
            <DependentUpon>Strings.resx</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Update="Strings.resx">
            <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
            <LastGenOutput>Strings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The EntryLibrary `csproj` looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Translations\Translations.csproj" PrivateAssets="all" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

For someone like me, who is not very familiar with the `nuspec` things, I just like the ease of `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>`, however building this shows the following warning:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221,5): warning NU5118: File '<Path-to-EntryLibrary>\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\pl\Translations.resources.dll' is not added because the package already contains file 'lib\netstandard2.0\Translations.resources.dll'
```

And it won't ship any localized `Translations.resources.dll`. It only works if all of these are directly part of the EntryLibrary, but I seperated them by intention into another library.

Is there any way to get this working without a dedicated `nuspec` configuration?

**UPDATE**

I made a demo solution, which can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/trdsolutions/resx-package-problem)

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot of your translation library project? What are the translation files called in your case?

Comment: @ewerspej I provided a demo solution. You can check it out and just build the "EntryLibrary" and you see the warning

Comment: One problem I noticed on first glance in your demo repo is that there is a typo in the Polish translation file: Strrings.pl-PL.resx. Also, are the translation DLLs correctly created in the output directory? There is no ```<OutputType>Library</OutputType>``` defined.

Comment: I'm only going to be able to check it out and build it tomorrow. Remind me, if I don't respond anymore ;)

Comment: I fixed the typo (it didn't changed anything). I think as not defined different, "Library" is the default, but I added this also to both.

Comment: It seems that satellite assemblies are only picked up from the library project that is being packed. I don't think I'll be able to help any further...

Comment: That's too bad, but thank you very much for your effort in here, I appreciate!